# Boto3 InvalidAccessKeyId in generate_presigned_post

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, chalice

I'm creating an AWS Lambda and API using Python's Chalice library. My AWS Credentials are injected using github workflow aws-actions and its able to `chalice deploy`. The endpoints are working and it's deploying perfectly to AWS.

The problem is:

I use Boto3 to create a presigned upload form using its function `generate_presigned_post` 
located in docs here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html

But when I use the response from that function and generate an html with it, after submitting the files to upload, it returns me

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
<Message>
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
</Message>
```

I checked everything and it seems it's using wrong AWS_ACCESS_KEY but if it's deploying to AWS perfectly, I figured it isn't the issue (at least for now). I use boto3 client and it seems to locate aws credentials automatically but it seems that it does not locate mine (or whatever is happening) and provides a wrong AWS_ACCESS_KEY.

```
import boto3

S3_CLIENT = boto3.client('s3')
BUCKET = 'bucket_name'

response = S3_CLIENT.generate_presigned_post(
            BUCKET,
            Key="{$filename}",
            Fields=None,
            Conditions=None,
            ExpiresIn=3600
        )
```

It returns correct response but when integrated with a form and used, the form returns the error.

Comment: *"I use Boto3 to create a presigned upload form using its function generate_presigned_post..."*  You will need to show us that part of your code. Please edit the question.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that! I added the snippet!

Comment: The invalid AWS Access Key Id is actually shown in the error, right?  Does it begin with `AKIA` or `ASIA`?  Do you recognize this key from anywhere?

Comment: The key starts with ASIA. I checked my IAM Users' access keys and nobody has the key starting with ASIA.

Comment: The credentials are injected within the github-actions workflow yaml file, I don't know why is it using a different key.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the key shouldn't be recognised from anywhere they are temporary credentials, no?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a little bit more complicated than it seems because of the nature of lambda and temporary keys.  Suffice to say you should follow these steps:

1. Create an IAM role with permissions to generate presigned urls for the bucket in question.
2. Take a lambda basic execution role and add permissions for that role to assume the role in step 1.
3. In your boto3 code, add a step to assume the role in step 1 before generating the signed url.  Something like this:

   ```
   import boto3

   sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

   assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
       RoleArn='arn_of_role_to_assume'
   )

   credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

   s3_client = boto3.client(
       's3',
       aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
       aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
       aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
   )

   s3_client.generate_presigned_url......
   ```